# How do i access a server drive through the web.config of a web service hosted on another server

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i have a web service that i am working on and i would like to be able to access a drive that is on another server. i know i need to create a setting in the web.config and i have done so but im getting the following error

URI formats are not supported.

my web.config settings

```
<setting name="FTP_FOLDER" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://xxx.xx.x.xx/F:\EDU-FTP</value>
  </setting>
```

Please assist me on the correct URI format for me to access the F: drive of another computer, through the web.config of a web service

Comment: if on same network, then a plain jane file share and you can use files and folders on that computer if they are shared. You may well need to create a new user on that server that allows the "web system user" from the web server to see and use those files.  So, FTP certainly no a choice unless that server has those services running. But this all comes down to what rights and what kind of network connection is from the web server to the other server with those files. And of course next question do URL's need to translate to those files (if yes, then create a virtual directory on the web server).

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal thank you for your answer, i actually want to upload files to the other server's drive

Comment: Ok, but then the question wonders back to if that server is on the same network as the web server. If it is, then you can use stanards windows path names in your web "code behind" to see + use those folders from the web server. This works like any computer on the same network. However, if the computer is not on your current network, then FTP or some web server service would have to be running on that other server. So the network connection options you have to the other server will define which road and path will work, and what your best options are. So, is other computer on same network?

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal the computers are on different networks

Comment: the folder to which i want to upload to is mapped on to the computer that is hosting the webservice as drive F:/. i have changed the value in the web.config to <setting name="FTP_FOLDER" serializeAs="String">
    <value>F:\</value>
  </setting>  On testing the file upload im now getting the 'can not find part of the path error'

Comment: ok, then you don't need FTP or anything. Your code behind can use plane jane standard windows path names to save the files up-loaded. Unless you create a web virtual folder, then those folders are not accessable by URL's, but code behind does not use web URL's, but simple windows path names. You can provide use of those files on the web site again by using code behind, or you can expose the folder(s) on that other server by creating what are called virtual folders. But, when a file is up-loaded, code behind does not use WEB URL's, but simple windows path names.